# IAP usage based billing

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, google-play-console

I want to charge my customer through my app depending on usage for example -  I create an app like Uber and I charge the taxi 1$ on each order created from the app and I collect it at the end of the month, can it be done in Google Play and the app store with IAP and what the rules about it, and if not can I use stripe to do it inside the App or external website that will charge the customer and he will get access to the app as well?